# Leer un archivo excel con python

Tags: python, macos, jupyter

Soy nuevo tanto con python como con mac, estoy intentando leer un archivo excel con python en jupiter pero tengo el error que se ve en la captura.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import os

absolutepath = os.path.abspath('excelPrueba.xlsx')
print(absolutepath)

df = pd.read_excel (r'/Users/XXXX/XXXX/excelPrueba.xlsx')
print (df)
```

**Error**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/pv/8071gcc161d5qzt1ynk48y5w0000gn/T/ipykernel_9674/2221932821.py in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_excel (r'/Users/XXXX/XXXX/excelPrueba.xlsx')
      2 print (df)

~/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    362     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    363         should_close = True
--> 364         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    365     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    366         raise ValueError(

~/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1231         self.storage_options = storage_options
   1232 
-> 1233         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
   1234 
   1235     def __fspath__(self):

~/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    519             passed to fsspec for appropriate URLs (see ``_get_filepath_or_buffer``)
    520         """
--> 521         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
    522         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
    523 

~/miniforge3/envs/tensorflow_m1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, errors, min_version)
    116     except ImportError:
    117         if errors == "raise":
--> 118             raise ImportError(msg) from None
    119         else:
    120             return None

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

Comment: Tanto el código como el error debe estar puesto como texto en la pregunta. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/491193/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: He añadido el código y el error. Gracias

Comment: Pues parece que pandas no se instaló bien y le falta el modulo `openpyxl`, ejecuta en una consola el comando `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: Eso es! Ha funcionado. Muchas gracias!